# Implement StoryShots for storybook with Angular

Tags: angular, storybook, visual-testing, storyshots

I'm running an Angular v8 app and within storybook. I want to integrate automated visual testing for it and found StoryShots. I found [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@storybook/addon-storyshots) instruction and implemented it like that. Because Karma the testing tool in the app, I adjust the jest config that only files with "test.ts" should be visually tested. Jest found the spec.ts files but only with test.ts file, it can't found the test `No tests found, exiting with code 1`. What did I missed? Anyone have some experience with angular and StoryShots?

This is my code:

`package.json`

```
  "scripts": {
   ...
    "jest": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "@angular/core": "^8.2.13"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
    "@storybook/addon-storyshots": "^5.2.8",
    "@storybook/angular": "^5.2.8",
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.23",
    "jest-preset-angular": "^8.0.0",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=10.15.0",
    "npm": "~6.4.0"
  }
```

`jest.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  preset: 'jest-preset-angular',
  roots: ['src'],
  setupFilesAfterEnv: [
    './jest.setup.ts'
  ],
  testMatch: [
    '**/__tests__/**/*.test.+(ts)?(x)' // <- only test.ts files
  ],
  globals: {
    __TRANSFORM_HTML__: true
  },
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.jsx?$': 'babel-jest',
    "^.+\\.(ts|js|html)$": "ts-jest"
  },
  moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'jsx', 'json', 'node', '.html']
};
```

`jest.setup.js`

```
import 'jest-preset-angular';
```

In the root folder I have a `.storybook` folder with the test file

`storyshots.test.ts`

```
import initStoryshots from '@storybook/addon-storyshots';

initStoryshots();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figure it out. The problem was that the `storyshot.test.ts` file wasn't in the src folder so I had to adjust the path in the `jest.config.js` like this

```
  rootDir: '../',
  modulePaths: [
    '<rootDir>'
  ],
```

Comment: Where exactly would this code be in jest.config.js?